# what's the point of microsoft 'windows genuine advantage' validation

Tags: updates

why do I have to jump through hoops to download bugfixes and upgrades? Is it a scam to collect information about my computer?

Comment: Too many voted this as off-stopic, but it's more of a superuser.com question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of Microsoft's  anti-piracy drive.

Comment: Dunno. I guess because someone considered even answering to a question of this kind as stupid. You get my +1. ;)